# underscore.js filter function using context

Tags: javascript, pointers, underscore.js

I am having trouble understanding how the _.filter() function works in undescorejs. Specifically, I am trying to understand if there is a way to return the values from the object being filtered, rather than the indices.

Assume the following:

```
var A = [1,2,3,4,5,8,10,12,15,20,25,30];
```

Now with a standard implementation:

```
_.filter(A, function(x) { return x % 5 == 0 ;})
```

This would return [5,10,15,20,25,30]. My problem arises with the following:

```
_.filter([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], function(x) { return this[x] % 5 == 0 ;}, A)
```

This returns [4,6] which are the indices of the true values (those divisible by 5). But I would like to return the values of the true indices from the original array, that being [5,10].

From my understanding of other underscore.js function such as _.each() and _.map() this is how I would call the function using context.

```
_.map([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], function(x) { return this[x] % 5 == 0 ; }, A)
```

Which would return [false,false,false,false,true,false,true]. I understand the _.filter() is calling _.each() internally to work through the array. So it makes sense that my call of `_.filter([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], function(x) { return this[x] % 5 == 0 ;}, A)` doesn't work, as the _.each() call is not receiving that `this[x]` value in its function.

Am I just missing something or is there just no way to call _.filter() that will return the values?

Comment: why do you need to use this?

Comment: @JordanHendrix I'm just trying to be better informed.

Comment: Your example is a bit convoluted, making it difficult to tell what part of these arrays are required to be used in your usage of _.filter. You could use underscore's chaining mechanism to then map over the result you get and return the values: http://underscorejs.org/#chain

Comment: @kinakuta Sorry for the poor wording. I was just trying to explain the difference in operation between the _.each() and _.filter() functions when using a context. After a more thorough reading of the source I believe the answer to be that within _.filter() the call of _.each() is called as `_.each(obj, function(value, index, list) { if (predicate(value, index, list)) results.push(value);})` So regardless of what the function passed to filter (predicate) returns, as long as the predicate resolves to true value is pushed to results. Where value is the index of the true value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somethisng like this?:

```
var indexes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
_.filter(A, function(x, i) {
    return x % 5 == 0 && indexes.indexOf(i) > -1;
});
```

[image]